# libinput touchscreen click event accuracy

Tags: touch-screen, libinput

I have a AdVantech Touchdisplay with Debian 10.

A `tap` results in a `click` event (all fine here).

But a `tap` with a little `move` does not.

If you have to control a touch device during while the hole machine is working (wiggle) it's a pain.

Is there any parameter I can set to fire a click (press) event when moving a little bit while tapping?

Here is the hardware listing ...

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PenMount PM1310                           id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver Mouse               id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver Consumer Control    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver System Control      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver Consumer Control    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

```
Device 'PenMount PM1310':
        Device Enabled (144):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (146): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Calibration Matrix (284):      1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Calibration Matrix Default (285):      1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (267):     1, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (268):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (269):        0, 0
        Device Node (270):      "/dev/input/event7"
        Device Product ID (271):        5345, 13576
```

Comment: what do you mean with 2x tap? I can not instruct anybody to double tap

Comment: I do not want to drag anything, I need to fire a click/press when the tap moves around a little bit

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no such parameter. However you've got an interesting usecase, I think it may warrant [reporting a feature request](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/issues?label_name%5B%5D=enhancement)